# davtest.pl Can't locate Net/SSL.pm

Tags: perl, security

I am newbie and I am using MacOS with brew and I had a problem with perl when I try to run davtest.pl I receive the following error `Can't locate Net/SSL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SSL module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.30 /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.30 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.30 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30) at davtest.pl line 49. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at davtest.pl line 49.`

I tried to install the perl module with cpan and I receive other error. I appreciate any kind of help. `openssl-version.c:2:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found #include <openssl/opensslv.h> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. Failed to build and link a simple executable using OpenSSL No 'Makefile' created  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK`

Comment: It requires the OpenSSL library. Including the header files. If you use your system's package manager, these are usually in a separate "-dev" or "-devel" package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.h` file referenced in the error message is part of the OpenSSL source code provided for writing packages the use OpenSSL; on my (CentOS 7) system, I had to install that with `yum install openssl-devel`, but your distro, and thus the way of installing `openssl-devel` may vary.